# Find closest time that has already occurred by time intervals-Android

Tags: java, android, datetime, time

This is in Android i have tried but with different mod

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTime(new Date());

            int unroundedMinutes = calendar.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
            int mod = unroundedMinutes % 4;
            calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, mod < 4 ? -mod : (4-mod));

            Date timeby4min = calendar.getTime();
```

What is the closest time interval(3:00,3:04,3:08....) to current time. Find closest time that has already occurred ie. current time 3:03 get closest time would be 3:00 for current time.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because [questions asking for (home)work help must include a summary of the work done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty solving it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: `LocalTime time = LocalTime.now(); time = LocalTime.of(time.getHour(), time.getMinute() / 4 * 4);`

Comment: `DateTime now = DateTime.now(); DateTime floored = now.withTime(now.getHourOfDay(), now.getMinuteOfHour() / 4 * 4, 0, 0);`

Comment: @shmosel Great minds... Of course, Android doesn't have a `LocalTime` or a `DateTime` class. ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just take the minutes and do Modulus 4 (4 being your apparent interval) on it then just always take the minutes minus the result of the modulus.

0%4 is 0

1%4 is 1

2%4 is 2

3%4 is 3

4%4 is 0

5%4 is 1 and so on...